# Importing big XML file (100k of records) into database

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am facing the problem the problem while parsing the XML. Its cosuming 47% of CPU and its very slow. It seems like DOM loads the XML into the memory and from there it starts reading the XML Tree node by node.

I am reading a node and dumping it to the Database.

I want a solution where I can read the XML without loading into the memory.

I am using JDK1.4.2_05.

Comment: `I want a solution where I can read the XML without loading into the memory.` - you meant that you wanted to load the XML partially, I suppose, for otherwise it is impossible to do anything useful in programming without loading something in memory. If so, use SAX/StAX, as using a DOM will always load the XML document completely in memory.

Comment: So you do not want to import the whole XML into database but only certain (well known) parts (nodes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for SAX parser, it's only way to do something with XML without build of full DOM in memory. There are some limitations but maybe it will suit your needs.

Comment: Hi,Thanks.I am using the SAX parser and its working according to my requirements. It parses more than 100 thousand records in only in 2-3 mins.

Comment: @Bharat: If the answer was satisfactory you should click on the check mark next to it in order to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) or SAX.

Answer (score 0):

The [Nux](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux//) project includes the [StreamingPathFilter](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux//api/nux/xom/xquery/StreamingPathFilter.html) class. With this class you can combine the streaming facilities and low memory footprint of SAX with the ease of use of DOM.

But this works only if your XML document has a record like structure. E.g. lots of `<person/>` elements.

(Following examples are taken from the Nux website and modified by me)

First you define how to handle one record:

```
StreamingTransform myTransform = new StreamingTransform() {
  public Nodes transform(Element person) {
    // Process person element, i.e. store it in a database
    return new Nodes(); // mark element as subject to garbage collection
  }
};
```

Then you create a `StreamingPathFilter` passing an XPath expression which matches to your record nodes.

```
// parse document with a filtering Builder
NodeFactory factory = new StreamingPathFilter("/persons/person", null).
                            createNodeFactory(null, myTransform);
new Builder(factory).build(new File("/tmp/persons.xml"));
```

The Nux library seems not maintained any more. But it is still usefull.